Airflow and EcsRunTaskOperator and specifying the target role
Struggling here, but I have this Airflow task:
thetask = EcsRunTaskOperator(
    task_id="mytask",
    cluster="mycluster",
    task_definition="mytask:11",
    aws_conn_id="aws",
    network_configuration={
        "awsvpcConfiguration": {
            "securityGroups": [...],
            "subnets": [...],
        }
    },
    overrides={
        "containerOverrides": [
            {
                "name": "mycontainer",
                "command": ["/bin/sh","-c,python","script.py"]
            }
        ]
    },
    launch_type="FARGATE"
)

This particular script accesses the AWS secret manager, so I get:
airflow.providers.amazon.aws.exceptions.EcsTaskFailToStart: The task failed to start due to: ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: unable to retrieve secrets from ssm: The task cannot pull secrets from AWS Systems Manager. There is a connection issue between the task and AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store. Check your task network configuration. RequestCanceled: request context canceled caused by: context deadline exceeded

This runs fine in ECS on a scheduled task, where that task assumes a "target role" that has access to ECR and the Secrets Manager.
I cannot figure out how to make this Airflow EcsRunTaskOperator assume that role so that it too has access to the secret manager.
